# OpenGraph embeds in discord with express&ejs

Tags: discord, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I am making a website with express.js and ejs, and I want to add OG embeds to it. Specifically, to be displayed when used in a message in Discord.
I have an `https://domain/devs` endpoint which returns a `.ejs` file with such code in the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="something">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/820672283289845760/827865044778745866/avatar.png">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://domain/devs">
```

Everything looks correct but nothing shows up when I use `https://domain/devs` in the message in Discord. What am I doing wrong? How to do that correctly?

P.S. To clarify what I mean for OG, I want `https://domain/devs` to display an embed like `https://www.youtube.com/` when used in a message

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard that you need a few more tags for Discord to recognize it, such as `og:description` and/or `og:site_name`. Since you have `og:image`, you should also consider adding `og:image:alt`.

I got mine working with only these three added to yours. Mine would fail load to because I had mispelled `description` as `decription`, but they started working immediately after fixing that typo.